# Use js global text replacement code with flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, text, replace

I have previously mapped JavaScript global text replacement lines of code (which is more than 100) as following example.It is hard to map them again to be compatible with flutter.

```
res = str.replace(/blue/g, "red");
res = str.replace(/black/g, "white");
res = str.replace(/green/g, "yellow");
.
.
.
```

I want use this mappings in flutter app to replace with input text and I'm newbie for flutter.Is there any method or trick I can use with thitext replacing mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [replaceAll](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method, it replaces all substrings that match from with replace.

```
var res;
res = str.replaceAll('blue', 'red');
res = str.replaceAll('black', 'white');
res = str.replaceAll('green', 'yellow');
...
```

Comment: Is there any method I can use res varibale multiple times in flutter?

Comment: Just like in JavaScript you can use the var keyword. @Axen_Rangs  (Have updated the answer above).